# How to redirect example.com/url to www.example.com/url using HipHop VM

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, hiphop, hhvm

How do I redirect example.com/url to www.example.com/url using HipHop VM. I'm not sure where to begin with since the rewriterules section seems to only apply pattern matching to the path

I've tried

```
RewriteRules {
    rootdomain {
      pattern = *
      to = http://www.example.com
      qsa = false
      redirect = 301

      conditions {
        * {
          pattern = ^example.com$
          type = host
          negate = false
        }
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I haven't had any luck with rewrite rules in HHVM, other seem to be using apache/nginx in front to do re-writing. Although, why would you want to add www?

Comment: @Letharion I dont want people saving/sharing links with/with out it and I like consistency. I could do a 301 redirect in php but that only works for php files and not images, css, etc.